# How to do Exact and Fuzzy search on same Elastic search fields

Tags: elasticsearch

We are trying to apply a fuzzy search on a field that is being analyzed using following analyzer

```
PUT test_index
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "max_ngram_diff": 40      
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete"
          ]
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "ngram",        
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 40
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "identifier": {
        "type": "text",            
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample data in the index is as follows

```
  PUT test_index/_doc/1
    { "identifier": "BANCM 2014 A2" }
    
    PUT test_index/_doc/2
    { "identifier": "BANCX 2014 A3" }
    
    PUT test_index/_doc/3
    { "identifier": "AMX 2007 A8" }
    
    PUT test_index/_doc/4
    { "identifier": "CARP 2021 G3" }
```

Search query used on identifier field is as follows for FUZZY search  :

```
GET test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "zipcode": {
        "identifier": "BAN 2014",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output for this fuzzy patch query would be

```
BANCM 2014 A2
BANCX 2014 A3
```

How can we implement an exact match on the same field at the same time which has been indexed as analyzed ?

Comment: Check if [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) will work for your case

Comment: How can have a field being in defined as analyzed and not analyzed for fuzzy and full text search using multi-fields approach

Comment: will using .keyword on analyze field work as an exact match